# Javascript object overwrites previouse objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So im trying to scrap html with javascript but having difficulty, every new object i add to array changes every previously added object:

```
$.get("Readfrom.php", null, function(html) {
  //console.log(html);
  var data = html;
  var uls = $("<ul>").html(data)[0].getElementsByTagName('ul');
  var length = uls.length;
  var elements;
  var object = {
    id: 'meh',
    name: '',
    lastN: '',
    identyfier: '',
  };
  var arrayb = new Array();
  for (var i = 2; i < length; ++i) {
    elements = $("<ul>").html(data)[0].getElementsByTagName('ul')[i].getElementsByTagName('li');

    var elemLength = elements.length;
    object.id = elements[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
    object.name = elements[1].firstChild.nodeValue;
    object.lastN = elements[2].firstChild.nodeValue;
    object.identyfier = elements[3].firstChild.nodeValue;
    arrayb.push(object);
    console.log(object);
  }
  console.log(arrayb);
}, "text");
```

This is console output i get for objects

```
Object { id: "1", name: "Peter", lastN: "La'habo", identyfier: "ABsdf23" }

Object { id: "2", name: "Liam", lastN: "Peters", identyfier: "dfghfgh54" }

Object { id: "3", name: "Super", lastN: "man", identyfier: "gff$$#'\\" }

Object { id: "4", name: "Jimmy\t", lastN: "Bobb's", identyfier: "fghj234\"234df" }

Object { id: "5", name: "Richárd", lastN: "Moore", identyfier: "dfghfg" }

Object { id: "6", name: "Jack", lastN: "Hurlock", identyfier: " fffffff" }

Object { id: "7", name: "Steve", lastN: "Stanley", identyfier: "fghgggg433" }
```

and this is the array

```
0: Object { id: "7", name: "Steve", lastN: "Stanley", … }

1: Object { id: "7", name: "Steve", lastN: "Stanley", … }
​
2: Object { id: "7", name: "Steve", lastN: "Stanley", … }
​
3: Object { id: "7", name: "Steve", lastN: "Stanley", … }
​
4: Object { id: "7", name: "Steve", lastN: "Stanley", … }
​
5: Object { id: "7", name: "Steve", lastN: "Stanley", … }
​
6: Object { id: "7", name: "Steve", lastN: "Stanley", … }
​
length: 7
```

im really confused at what's going on here. why new objects overwrite every prevus one?

Comment: Because the reference for `object` is never reassigned to a new object. So you're just repeatedly modifying the same object and pushing the same reference to the array multiple times.

Comment: but then why is it only last object that fills all spaces?

Comment: the "last object" _is all the objects_, as in they're all referencing the same piece of memory. Obviously the last time you change its properties, they're not overwritten by anything else, so that's what it looks like when you're done.

Comment: @Karolis His last sentence explains that.  You're modifying the *same* object, and adding that *same* object to the array multiple times.

Comment: how could i reassign reference to a new object? example would be kinda helpful :D

Comment: nvm i fixet it, thanks a lot, spent like 1 h trying to figure it out :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming everything else is correct, here's a slightly less tedious way to declare each object:

```
$.get("Readfrom.php", null, function(html) {
  var arrayb = $("<ul>")
    .html(html)
    .find('ul')
    .toArray()
    .slice(2) // starting at index 2
    .map(function (ul) {
      var elements = $(ul).children('li');

      return {
        id: elements[0].firstChild.nodeValue,
        name: elements[1].firstChild.nodeValue,
        lastN: elements[2].firstChild.nodeValue,
        identyfier: elements[3].firstChild.nodeValue
      };
    });

  console.log(arrayb);
}, "text");
```

Answer (score 0):

You re pushing the same declaration of "object".

Try declaring object variable inside the for

```
    $.get("Readfrom.php",null,function(html){
//console.log(html);
var data=html;
var uls=$("<ul>").html(data)[0].getElementsByTagName('ul');
var length= uls.length;
var elements;
var arrayb= new Array();
for (var i=2;i<length;++i)
{

let object={
id:'meh',
name:'',
lastN:'',
identyfier:'',
};
elements=$("<ul>").html(data)[0].getElementsByTagName('ul')[i].getElementsByTagName('li');

var elemLength=elements.length;
object.id=elements[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
object.name=elements[1].firstChild.nodeValue;
object.lastN=elements[2].firstChild.nodeValue;
object.identyfier=elements[3].firstChild.nodeValue;
arrayb.push(object);
console.log(object);


}
console.log(arrayb);
},"text");
```

Comment: @Rawrplus what...? And no, your last sentence is wrong. JavaScript has a GC, which only frees memory when there are no more accessible references to it, i.e. it "falls out of scope". `arrayb` is still in scope, therefore the objects it contains will not be freed.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts never mind, I actually misinterpreted the code, my bad.

Comment: Though I will admit it seems silly to initialize an object with default properties, only to overwrite all of them. Either assign them in the declaration, or initialize an empty object.

Answer (score 0):

Objects are references. When you pass an object to a function, or put it into an array, or use it anywhere, you are passing a pointer to its location in memory. You are *not* passing a *snapshot* of it at that point in time. If the object changes later, all references to that location in memory change too.

```
// x points to location 1 in memory.
var x = {};              

// Location 1 in memory has its one property set to 1.
x.one = 1;               

// myArray gets passed location 1 in memory, NOT a copy of location 1.
myArray.push(x);         

// Location 1 in memory has its two property set to 2.
x.two = 2;               

// Outputs location 1 in memory, which is now { one: 1, two: 2 }.
console.log(myArray[0]);
```

If you want a *copy* of an object, you need to create a new object (creating a new location in memory), not mutate an old one.